# Microchip MLA file does not compile

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab

I tried to compile an MLA file without success. The IDE keep telling me that "No such file or directory." Any idea how I can solve this problem?

[image]

How can I change the directory of these templates?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem reinstalling the MLA and using the default installation path.
I hope this can help someone else with the same problem.

[image]